# When does a singular value of a square invertible matrix become an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with real entries. I know that its largest singular value, $\sigma_{\max}$ is equal to its operator norm. Moreover, there are singular vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

\begin{equation}
Au=\sigma_{\max}v, \qquad A^Tv=\sigma_{\max}u
\end{equation}

by definition of the singular value. However, generally $u$ and $v$ are not the same, so that $\sigma_{\max}$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $A$. I wonder when $\sigma_{\max}$ becomes an eigenvalue of $A$, so that there is nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=\lVert A \rVert x$.

Comment: Consider the symmetric case, then the symmetric and positive semidefinite one